# Rollback framework from 4.5.1 to 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, frameworks

Hi I have to recompile my website from .NET Framework 4.5.1 to 4.0.30319 because of what is installed on the web server running IIS 6.  When I select recompile the website and run it I am receiving a number of errors similar to this:

> The type or namespace name 'Membership' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
>   C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\RF\Account\OpenAuthProviders.ascx.cs

How do I either exclude these references or enable them to run on framework 4?  ~if possible?

Comment: To resolve this I removed the reference to:  Microsoft.AspNet.OpenAuthProviders in the package.config file then removed the .dll reference to this then removed all auto generated pages in the web app that had a reference to this namespace, thankfully hadn't used anything from it then reinstalled all nuget assembly packages to the right versions.  working now...

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, and mark it as the answer :) #freerep